# Approximate a discrete second derivative with assymetric points

Tags: discrete-mathematics, derivatives, approximation

Good morning.

I need to approximate the second derivative for a discrete function with only few points. My first intuition was to use the traditionnal formula:
[approximation of the second derivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Pnd.png)

Unfortunately my available points are not at symmetrical distance from to the other. In consequence I have clearly doubtful results, with positivesecond derivative while my function is concave.

My question is, do have I to modify the coefficients in my formula to take into account the asymmetry between my two points ? And if I have to do so, which weights to use ?
If my intuition is false, what would you recommend to me to do to take into account the assymetry ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please, don't upload an image when it is not strictly necessary. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead.

Comment: Starting from the Taylor series expansion $$f(x_0+h) = f(x_0) +\dfrac{f'(x_0)}{1!}h +\dfrac{f''(x_0)}{2!}h^2 +\dfrac{f'''(x_0)}{3!}h^3 +\ldots,$$ you may disregard higher-degree terms (starting from some degree $n$ of your choice) to get approximations. Also, you may play with the $h$ value and its sign in the Taylor approximation ($h \to -h$, $h \to 2h$, $h \to -2h$, etc.) and then combine the approximations ($f(x+h)-f(x-h)$ or $f(x+h)-f(x-2h)$) to try and cancel some of the lower-degree terms. This may be easier to show if you provide the points available to compute your second derivative.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying so quickly. For example, my three points are A= (5; 0.049878), B= (10; 7.30607) and C=(13; 30.075539). And I would like the second derivative for the point B

Comment: The natural generalization of the formula in your question (which is known as the *central difference formula* for the second derivative) can be obtained as follows. You have three points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$. There is a unique parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ that passes through these points. Find it, and then obtain the second derivative as $2a$. If you did this for equally spaced points, you would get exactly the formula you are familiar with.

Comment: For example, the parabola passing through your three points $(5, 0.049878)$, $(10, 7.30607)$, $(13, 30.075539)$ is approximately $0.7673 x^2 - 10.01 x + 31.16$, so the estimate of the second derivative is $1.5346$.

Comment: I like your approach, unfortunately by doing this you assume that these points follow a polynomial form, which is not always my case

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** we are dealing with approximations here; answers are neither unique nor exact, but consistent.

Let us say you want to approximate 
$$f'(9) \approx \dfrac{f(13) -f(5)}{13-5} \text{ as in }f'(x_0) \approx \dfrac{f(x_0+h) -f(x_0-h)}{2h} \text{ where }x_0=9, h=4.$$ 
Then, approximate $f'(10)$ either by 
$$f'(10) \approx \dfrac{f(10) -f(5)}{10-5} \text{ as in } f'(x_0) \approx \dfrac{f(x_0) -f(x_0-h)}{h} \text{ where } x_0=10, h=5;$$ 
or by 
$$f'(10) \approx \dfrac{f(13) -f(10)}{13-10} \text{ as in } f'(x_0) \approx \dfrac{f(x_0+h) -f(x_0)}{h} \text{ where } x_0=10, h=3.$$
So then you can approximate 
$$f''(10) \approx \dfrac{f'(10) -f'(9)}{10-9} \text{ as in } g'(x_0) \approx \dfrac{g(x_0) -g(x_0-h)}{h} \text{ where } x_0=10, h=1, g=f'.$$

Comment: Thanks, I undestand the practical intuition behind this result. By any chance, could you tell me to which theory does this refer ?

Comment: Consider this definition:
$$f'(x_0):=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}.$$
For $h$ not so small, you can think of this quotient as a "right-hand" approximation:
$$f'(x_0)\approx\dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h},$$
which is the second formula I propose to estimate $f'(10)$. You may instead consider this other definition:
$$f'(x_0):=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x_0)-f(x_0-h)}{h}.$$
Again, for $h$ not so small you may think of a "left-hand" estimate:
$$f'(x_0)\approx\dfrac{f(x_0)-f(x_0-h)}{h},$$
as in computing $f'(10)$ first ver., and $f''(10)$.

Comment: For this little guy over here:
$$f'(x_0)\approx\dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{2h},$$
Consider the Taylor series expansion as in my very first comment yesterday, then truncate it up to the $h$ term (or the $h^2$) since you aim to estimate $f''(x_0)$ and call it a Taylor approximation:
$$f(x_0+h)\approx f(x_0)+h\cdot f'(x_0).$$
If you then change the sign of $h$ you get
$$f(x_0-h)\approx f(x_0)-h\cdot f'(x_0).$$
You can combine these two to estimate a $f'(x_0)$ with symmetric points $x_0-h$ and $x_0+h$:
$$f'(x_0)\approx\dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{2h},$$
as in computing $f'(9)$.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292409/asymmetric-second-difference-quotient) (alas!) to which your task relates heavily to. 
Consider the formula you posted as an image:
$$f''(x)\approx\dfrac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}. \tag{1}$$
It actually came from this:
$$f''(x)\approx\dfrac{\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\dfrac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}}{h}.$$
The generalization for three asymmetric points is
$$f''(x)\approx\dfrac{\dfrac{f(x+h_2)-f(x)}{h_2}-\dfrac{f(x)-f(x-h_1)}{h_1}}{\dfrac{h_1+h_2}{2}},$$
which simplifies to
$$f''(x)\approx\dfrac{\dfrac{2h_1}{h_1+h_2}\cdot f(x+h_2)-2f(x)+\dfrac{2h_2}{h_1+h_2}\cdot f(x-h_1)}{h_1h_2}. \tag{2}$$
When plugging $h=h_1=h_2$ in $(2)$, you end up with the symmetric case $(1)$.
For your specific points ($x=10$, $h_1=5$, $h_2=3$; compute $(h_1+h_2)/2=4$ beforehand) you have
$$f''(10)\approx\dfrac{\tfrac{5}{4}f(13)-2f(10)+\tfrac{3}{4}f(5)}{5\cdot 3}.$$